# iOS: swipe gesture inside a subview

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, swipe

I should implement a swipe gesture inside a subview; this subview is a oblique view

```
view1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( ( 54 * -M_PI ) / 180 );
```

I want implement the swipe gesture inside this view, if it happens I should have a NSLog that say that swipe happens inside this view, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as with any other UIView, it's possible to add a gesture recognizer:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
[view1 addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

The problem lies in the UISwipeGestureRecognizer's property 'direction'. Apple documentation about this property:

> The permitted direction of the swipe for this gesture recognizer.

Because the view is rotated, directions rotate along. If the view is rotated 180 degrees and the user swipes right, the gesture recognizer sees it as a left swipe. I'd suggest using a wrapper view on which the gesture recognizer should be placed. Try this:

```
UIView *view2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:view1.frame];
[view1.superview addSubview:view2];

view2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
[view2 addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureRecognizer];
```

The disadvantage is that there are certain areas within view2 but outside view1 which will respond to the gesture recognizer.